# How to reduce the bandwith with very high sample frequency on USRP

Tags: gnuradio, usrp

I am using USRP with DBSRX daughter board.
I need a very high sample frequency. Currently, the USRP can give me
maximum sample frequency of  64M/8 in I and Q, and the data type is
short, which takes 2 bytes.

So can I decrease the length of the output data? for example save the
data as char which takes 1 bytes, and increase the sample frequency to
64M/4.
Can I do this? and how?

Answer (score 2):

$ usrp_rx_cfile.py --help

See the -8 option which gets you 8-bit I & Q and allows a minimum
decimation factor of 4.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in different ways, one is the was user19899 explained. The more 'difficult' way is to modify the FPGA code of the USRP and add a loss-less compression before the UHD interface. On the driver side, you must add an extra layer to your code to to the opposite.

I did that for another platform where we saved close to 40% bandwidth using this solution.